# Json не возвращает null поле

Tags: java, json

Есть поле String, которое может быть null. И вот если оно null, то в ответе в json этот null не показывается. Как сделать что б показывалось?
json формируется след образом

```
return JSONObject().put("name", name);
```

Comment: зачем его показывать?

Comment: потому что если оно null, его тоже надо передать. Ибо если поле null, то в ответе на запрос его вообще нет, а когда ответ на клиенте парсится, то будет ошибка, если поля нет. Или я не прав?

Comment: если поля нет, то и ошибки тоже нет, когда парсится то если поля нет то значение поля null, по крайней мере все знакомые мне парсеры так поступают.

Comment: потом будешь обращаться к этому полю и будет ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject().put("name", name == null ? JSONObject.NULL : name);
```

Comment: А можно ли как то это сделать для всего Json? Что б не писать это около каждого поля.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) - он умеет сериализовывать `null`, надо создавать объект `Gson` так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

Далее сериализуем:

```
gson.toJson(myObject, MyObject.class); //будет писать null члены класса MyObject
```